# Calculate the limit of $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{1-x^2}{\sin \pi x}$ only with the fundamental limits

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

I have this limit

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{1-x^2}{\sin \pi x} \tag 1$$

which can be solved, easily, by De l'Hospital's rule (the solution is $2/\pi$). I have considered that $x\to 1$, therefore $t=x-1\to 0$. We have also $t+2=x+1$.

Hence:
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{1-x^2}{\sin \pi x} =\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{-t(t+2)}{\sin \pi (t+1)}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\pi (t+1)}{\sin \pi (t+1)}\cdot \frac{-t(t+2)}{\pi (t+1)}\tag 2$$
but with the

$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\pi (t+1)}{\sin \pi (t+1)}\cdot \frac{-t(t+2)}{\pi (t+1)}\equiv 0$$
and I have not found the solution $2/\pi$. Why?

Comment: $\sin(\pi +0) =0$ so your conclusion is not correct.

Comment: Recall that $\sin \alpha(x)\sim \alpha (x)$ only if $\alpha(x) \to 0$.

Comment: @dfnu $\sin \pi(t+1)\sim \pi(t+1)$. In fact $\pi(t+1)\to 0$ when $t\to 0$.

Comment: @Sebastiano when $t \to 0$ you have $\pi (t+1) \to \pi$.

Comment: @dfnu It is true. I have to ask myself because when I'm tired I don't see these trivialities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $t=x-1$. Then we have

$$\frac{1-x^2}{\sin(\pi x)}=\frac{-t(t+2)}{\sin(\pi (t+1))}=\frac{t(t+2)}{\sin(\pi t)}$$

Now, set $\pi t=y$ to find

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{1-x^2}{\sin(\pi x)}=\lim_{y\to 0}\left(\frac1\pi(y/\pi+2)\frac{y}{\sin(y)}\right)$$

Can you finish?

Comment: Sorry for my delay to accept your answer.

Comment: Hi Sebastiano.  Thank you for the nice note!

Comment: Very mind Mark my mind is always above the clouds. I'm always overwhelmed and worried.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial change of variables was good, but then you have to use the correct manipulation:

$$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{-t}{\sin(\pi t + \pi)} \cdot (t+2) = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{-\pi t}{-\sin(\pi t)} \cdot \frac{t+2}{\pi} = 1 \cdot \frac{2}{\pi} = \frac{2}{\pi}$$

Comment: I'm sleeping :-( it's true. I'm too scarce :-( and I didn't see this obvious banality.

Comment: Now to whom should I give the green tick that these are two good answers? :-( I am thanking you differently.

Answer (score 1):

I'll propose a variant to simplify a bit the computations: setting $x=1-t$, which is the same as $t=1-x$, you get
$$\frac{1-x^2}{\sin(\pi x)}=\frac{(1-x)(1+x)}{\sin(\pi x)}=\frac {t(2-t)}{\sin(\pi-\pi t)}=\underset{\stackrel{\textstyle\downarrow}{\tfrac1\pi}}{\frac{t}{\sin\pi t}}\,\underset{\stackrel{\textstyle\downarrow}{2}}{(2-t)}$$

Comment: You're right. Very nice answer. +1 also for you.